# Hightcharts - multiple data in one single pie charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Whats the best way to achieving the below pie chart using Highcharts library. This pie chart has multiple data in one single pie chart.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pattern-fill` module to distinguish some points on the chart:

```
var data = [{
  y: 2.5,
  color: '#004512'
}, {
  y: 9.5,
  color: '#453813',
  dataGroup: 1
}, ...];

data.forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.dataGroup) {
    el.color = {
      pattern: {...}
    }
  }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4772/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/pattern-fills/

Comment: Appreciate it. But how do I get the dual legend with split slice (Test 4)? The solid and dotted represent another chart within the chart.

Comment: Hi @Dreg Artor, You can create another chart and position them under the first. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4773/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, this looks much better. Appreciate it. Could you please let me know how to add a different pattern to it? thin line or may be dots. I think you have used SVG paths in this.

Comment: You need to edit the `path` property. Please check docs from the answer.